# Automate Go Build Commands before deploying on Heroku

Tags: go, heroku

So I am working on a Go Project using the Heroku CLI

Now, whenever I want to `heroku local` I have to first of all do `go build -o bin/myappName.exe -v`.

Is there a way to automate the  `go build -o bin/myappName.exe -v` command, so that whenever I do
`heroku local` then `go build -o bin/myappName.exe -v` happens automatically before the local deployment.

Thanks alot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why not using a Makefile, so you can apply a command that internally does what you need.

```
heroku-deploy:
    go build -o bin/myappName.exe -v && heroku local
```

the run `make heroku-deploy`

if you are using windows you can install [cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/) to run the make command.

Comment: That was badass!!! Worked like a charm. Thanks alot.I truly appreciate.